# Load Remote URL in Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i want to open an external url of a newsletter signup form in a bootstrap modal.

this is the newsletter signup form:

```
<form action="external-action.html" id="newsletter-form" class="newsletter-form">
<label for="newsletter-input">label:</label>
<input type="text" value="newsletter" onfocus="this.value='';" name="newsletter-input">
<input type="submit" class="save-button" value="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#myModal">
</form>
```

Any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to POST the form and have the results open up in a modal?

Comment: Yeh I was thinking `IFRAME` with `target=` for the POST.